# Convert input lines into specific format

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash

Hello Experts,

I've entries like below in my input file.

```
    A3YZ.SX.6_A3YZ.SX.7
    AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4
```

In above example, underscore has been used to combine the multiple rules into a single line. Apparently my flow require them to split into multiple entries where the first column should be the line and second should have patterns derived from each line. i.e.

```
example1::
    A3YZ.SX.6_A3YZ.SX.7 A3YZ.SX.6
    A3YZ.SX.6_A3YZ.SX.7 A3YZ.SX.7

example2::

    AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.1
    AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.2
    AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.3
    AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.4
```

Is there a way to do that?

Regards,
Divesh

Answer (score 3):

Using `perl` from the command line:

```
$ perl -F'_' -lane 'for my $ele ( @F ) { print "$_ $ele" }' file
A3YZ.SX.6_A3YZ.SX.7 A3YZ.SX.6
A3YZ.SX.6_A3YZ.SX.7 A3YZ.SX.7
AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.1
AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.2
AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.3
AB3Y.OMG.1_AB3Y.OMG.2_AB3Y.OMG.3_AB3Y.OMG.4 AB3Y.OMG.4
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches:**

- `-F'_'`: Sets the input field separator to `_`.
- `-l`: Chomp the newline during processing and places it back during print.
- `-a`: Autosplit the input line based on the field separator and populates an array `@F`.
- `-n`: Creates an implicit `while(<>) { ... }` loop to process each line.
- `-e`: Executes the code block that follows it.

**Code:**

We iterate over the array (`@F`) we created using `-F` and `-a` options and prints the entire line along with the array element.

Comment: wow Jaypal!! it's quite quick and simple. There is one scenario which I forgot earlier. In case if  have something like below       ABCD.XRLX.1_ABCD.XRLX.2_1 GSD.RL.1
GSD.RL.1_GSD.RL.2_1 GSD.RL.2                                          both the approaches will split them into 3 parts against the two .. so we will need to ignore a pattern if just a number digit.

Comment: @DiveshRastogi Can you please update your question to include this and also add the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use split to split by `_(?=\s|\w(?!\s))|\s` and then append your original string to each result and get your output.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/27

Comment: Thanks vks. There is one scenario which I forgot earlier. In case if have something like below                  ABCD.XRLX.1_ABCD.XRLX.2_1 GSD.RL.1 GSD.RL.1_GSD.RL.2_1 GSD.RL.2 both the approaches will split them into 3 parts against the two .. so we will need to ignore a pattern if just a number digit.

Comment: Could you please check following link again? There is one scenario which doesn't get divided. "http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/26"

Comment: thanks vks. Unfortunately, the code is not working when i transfer it to the script. Here is the snippet of the code ....                                                        my @tmpA= split(" _(?=\s|\w(?!\s))|\s", $_);                    ....                        Could you please correct this to make it work? I don't why underscore is not getting copied in above code.                    Regards,

Comment: @DiveshRastogi i tried the same in python and the ouput was as expected.Use regex.split not simple split.